# Wordpress get thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I have a problem. I need to get the thumbnail of my picture. I have this addon called custom fields where i can add fields to a post, fill them out and get them out with `the_field('picture1', $page->ID);` in my php code.

I have several of those fields etc. picture2, picture 3 and so on.

But i need to get the thumbnail of the picture. I can either get an output with the image object, the id of the picture or the url of the picture.

How do i get the url of the thumbnail? I've been trying things like

```
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('picture1', $page->ID), 'thumbnail');
```

But all i get is a empty output. What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using

```
$image_1 = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('image1', $page->ID), 'thumbnail');
echo $image_1[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('picture1', $page->ID), 'thumbnail');
```

If you read the codex for [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src), you can see that it returns an array.

**Return Value**

An array containing: 
0 => url, 
1 => width, 
2 => height, 
3 => boolean: true if $url is a resized image, false if it is the original or if no image is available.

So for the url you would need to get the first item of the array `$thumb[0]`.